# Error 1042 MySql C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, console, connection

I can't connect to my MySql database via my C# cmd it gets me error 1042
this code is from:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/67226fe6-175a-4f8b-96ab-a22fd836617f/inserting-values-to-mysql-using-c

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

class MyClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
        string SQL;

    conn.ConnectionString = "server=SERVER; userid=USER;password=PASSWORD;database=DATABASE;";
    try
         {
            conn.Open();
             MessageBox.Show("Files Inserted into database successfully!",
                    "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
             conn.Close();
        }
        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex.Number + " has occurred: " + ex.Message,
                "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
}
}
```

UPDATE - SOLVED
SOLVED the server name was a bad url
i used
[db4free.net](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/67226fe6-175a-4f8b-96ab-a22fd836617f/inserting-values-to-mysql-using-c)
maybe the dash in my host was the problem

Comment: To add some clarification: the MySQL 1042 (HY000) error is due the the failure of the MySQL server to resolve the IP address of the **client** connecting to the database. An attempt to connect from the client to a server hostname that can't be resolved, that would result in MySQL error 2005 (11001), which is client error. (Error  numbers beginning with a "1" are errors reported by the **server**, error numbers beginning with "2" are errors reported by the **client**.

Answer (score 5):

MySQL error 1042 (HY000) is reported from the MySQL server when it can't resolve the client IP address into a hostname.

On our MySQL servers, we disable hostname resolution, and use IP addresses instead.

If you don't want to disable hostname resolution, then you need to ensure that MySQL can resolve your client IP address into a hostname, either by adding an appropriate entry to the /etc/hosts file (on the MySQL server host),  or adding an appropriate entry to the DNS server(s).

Otherwise, you can disable hostname resolution by adding `skip-name-resolve` in the `[mysqld]` section of the MySQL server configuration file (and restarting the MySQL server).  **NOTE:** Any current users defined using a hostname won't be able available, since MySQL will now be looking (defined in the mysql.users table) for users of the form  "`foo@192.168.1.33`", rather than "`foo@tyrion`", and MySQL isn't going to find a match.  (This isn't a problem if your users are all defined with the `%` wildcard as the hostname.)

Comment: "Error 1042 - Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts"
The issue here is the client is not able to resolve or connect to the server.
If you see this in server logs you might be correct, but if you see this on the client then it is not the server that sends that error code.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue,i was tring to connect to remnote mysql server using my window 7 os machine but in my case disabling firewall solved my problem